# How to add filter condition while getting data from edge collection in arangodb

Tags: node.js, arangodb

I'm trying to get data from edge collection based on a condition

In my edge collection, I have data like below

```
{
    _from: "rooms/1"
    _to: "users/1"
    type: "admin"
},{
    _from: "rooms/1"
    _to: "users/2"
    type: "member"
},{
    _from: "rooms/1"
    _to: "users/3"
    type: "member"
}
```

Now I want to get user info of admin only. I try with the below query but it is returning null values

```
FOR r IN rooms
    FILTER r._key == 1
    let admins = (
        FOR u IN ANY r rooms_users
            FILTER rooms_users.type == "admin"
        RETURN u
    )
RETURN MERGE([r, {admin: admins [0]}])
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three minor issues...

First, the `_key` attribute is always a string, so you need to quote the `1` in the first filter.

Second, in the "admins" subquery, you can't filter on "rooms_users" because that's the name of the edge collection, not the identification of the edge document(s).  To filter on an attribute of an edge, you need to add a variable to the `FOR` statement to identify the edge (`e` in this case) - [docs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-traversals.html).

Last, for performance reasons, I changed the graph query from `ANY` to `INBOUND` and gave it a limit of `1`.  This means we will only find: (a) admins of THIS room, and won't traverse long directions up and down the graph trying to find any and all documents (it actually wound in a loop for me and timed out).

```
FOR r IN rooms
    FILTER r._key == '1'
    LET admins = (
        FOR u,e IN 1 INBOUND r rooms_users
            FILTER e.type == 'admin'
            RETURN u
    )
    RETURN MERGE([r, { admin: admins[0] }])
```